# MSAL Authentication - WASM Web application - Failed to construct URL

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, webassembly, azure-ad-msal

I need you clever peoples help.

I need to get msal authentication working with EntraID. I have a net 6 wasm application and I am getting daft errors - I must have looked at my appsettings.json file 100 times for a typo.

I am getting the error :

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
> TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
> at new u (https://localhost:7151/_content/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/AuthenticationService.js:2:191011)
> at l.init (https://localhost:7151/_content/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/AuthenticationService.js:2:196273)

My web app to get the msal working as very very basic indeed, nothing special here.
Appsettings.json file

[image: appsettings.json]

Index.html

AuthWebApp
    
    
    
    


    Loading...

```
<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script src="_content/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
```

Program.cs

```
using AuthWebApp;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
});


await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

index.razor

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

@attribute [Authorize]

<h1>User needs to be in AD for this page to work</h1>
```

Authentication.razor

```
@page "/Authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@action"></RemoteAuthenticatorView>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string ?action { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot seem to get over this error and the logging is pretty useless on the browser. THe app registration is just a basic one with the redirect set to :

https://localhost:7151/Authentication/login-callback

anyone with any quick ideas ?

Comment: Are you getting the error running locally or after deploying? I have the same error as you when I deploy to Azure App Service but can run locally with the same configuration with no issue

Comment: Try adding:

`<ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" />
  </ItemGroup>`

To the Client .csproj file